# To many print results - for key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Good morning everyone,

There are a number of posts on here somewhat related to this however I am newer and a hands on learner so it's difficult to grasp the solutions offered on other peoples coding when I don't necessarily know their end goal. This is the first time I have tried to apply my coding skills (or lack thereof :D) but I have been working through m1mo and reading/watching an assortment of guides/tutorials the last couple of months. So yes my code may look goofy to a lot of you but got to start somewhere!

***Goal***: I want to pull the dictionary value from product_dict of the key that is in the c_item_number_one, which this code does successfully, but if the key does **not** appear in the dictionary then I want to print("Not in dictionary")

***Issue***: While the code does provide the dictionary value based on the key there will be times when the c_item_number_one does not include a valid key. When this happens, I want to know by print("Not in dictionary"). Currently this code will print "Not in dictionary" for **every single dictionary entry** that does not appear in my product_dict. I only want it to tell me once in the event it does not appear a single time.

There will also be times, like in this example, where multiple keys are found within the dictionary, **this is okay.** I want it to print all of these instances as I will be adding further validation when this occurs in later code.

Note that the below is a small sample of the actual dictionary and that I have roughly 1200 entries in reality with more to be added as time goes on.

"Product" is only one of a dozen categories I need to pull from descriptions so any help here will greatly help me towards the end game and be very much appreciated!

```
product_dict = {
    'BEND': 'BEND',
    'FABRICATE SPOOL': 'PIPE SPOOL',
    'STUB-END': 'STUB END',
    'GSK': 'GASKET',
    'SA-106': 'PIPE',
    'PIPE': 'PIPE',
}

c_item_number_one = '12",PIPE , GR. B, SCH 40, WALL SMLS'

#Product for Item One
def item_one_product():
    found = True
    for key in product_dict:
        if key in c_item_number_one:
            item_number_one_product = product_dict[key]
            print(item_number_one_product)
        else:
            found = False
            print("Not in dictionary")

item_one_product()
```

It prints:

```
Not in dictionary
Not in dictionary
Not in dictionary
Not in dictionary
PIPE
PIPE
```

Comment: Be careful while using `in` with string. For example suppose your `c_item_number` does not contain `PIPE` but it has `PIPER`, the `in` will tell yes happily.

Comment: Best approach is to split the string by `,` then do `in` check

Comment: What is `c_item_number_one` a list?. Are you trying to find the values in dictionary by using key as the elements of list `c_item_number_one`. if the key is present you want to print the value. Else 'Not in dictionary'?

Comment: @Epsi95 - I am concerned about this as well however this is something I plan to address next by pulling all words related to the returned value and getting rid of the undesired ones.

Splitting the string doesn't seem like it would work as we have a lot of products that also appear in other forms. An example is that we have Flanges and Flangolets, Pipe and piperacks, and more.

Comment: @Akansha - c_item_number_one will eventually be input but is just an integer currently but is not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, check this:

```
#Product for Item One
def item_one_product():
    not_found = True
    for key in product_dict:
        if key in c_item_number_one:
            item_number_one_product = product_dict[key]
            print(item_number_one_product)
            not_found = False
    if not_found:
        print("Not in dictionary")

item_one_product()
```